# Css background image hack with larger images (CSS Sprites)

Tags: css, background-image

How intelligently browsers implement "css background image hacks" and is this technique memorywise to use with larger images?

The example can be this page (Look at eg. the plus icon):
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

The plus icon is not really a 16x16px image, it is larger (469px x 159px) and actually this:
http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
(or this: http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png )

This image is used as an icon-template, which contains all icons and in css ( http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css ) the background image position is adjusted to show only a specific area of the icon-template this way:
`.icon-plus{background-position:-408px -96px;}`

What if the icon is larger, eg. thumbnails of size 150px x 150px and icon-template consist of 500 images? The icon-template is then 37500px x 37500px. Can browser handle this in a reasonable way or is it better to load those thumbnails one at a time, every in its own http-process?

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called **CSS Sprites**, It is used to cut down your http requests, and hence your page loads faster.

Explanation :

all the images used in a website are placed on a single canvas, and than each image is mapped using a `background-position` property, this way, the http request cuts down thus making your web page load faster.

> Say for example you have 10 `<img>` tags calling 10 different Images,
>   hence browser need to request 10 different images 10 times, thus
>   increasing http requests, if all these images are placed on a single
>   canvas/image(mostly transparent png's) and it is just loaded once and
>   CSS handles the rest..

This is really useful when you use image on hovering a button or something else, as it's already loaded you wont see a flick while hovering it...

[**For More Reference**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: How about larger images? If canvas is 37500px x 37500px and there are 500 icons of size 150px x 150 px?

Comment: you need to cut down the appropriate image you want on your website before making a sprite, moreover you can also check this out CSS3  `background-size:whateverpx whateverpx;`

Comment: yea it is useful if your website traffic increases, it increases page loading time, you just have to be clever what to use when, using 3-4 images wont make huge difference, if you've many images, it does make difference, popular websites like google, facebook, etc widely use this, just for your info, images used as a background wont be draggabble..

Comment: I understand that, but my question was "How intelligently browsers implement ... and is this technique memorywise to use with larger images?" I'm not sure if your answer is the right answer to the question at it's current state.

Comment: there's no browser intelligence in this, it is just css hack, browser just render what you instruct it too, instead it is smart technique by using CSS

Comment: Yes, I believe the techinque is smart, but I have not yet seen any comparative example of large canvas (37500px x 37500px) vs. 500 single images of size 150px x 150px. Which one is quicker and which one eats less RAM memory.

Comment: RAM has nothing to do with it, larger the image size more it takes time to load, but if you've 500 images of 150x150 it is surely recommended to split these images in 10 sprites and load it as and when required on respective page because if you load on the first page it will take huge time to load, and this will be drastically cutting down your http requests..I did gave you a reference link did you even read it?

Comment: I'd appreciate some sort of performance test which compares memory consumption and page load time in large canvas (37500x37500px) compared to single image loads (150x150px). Maybe I have to create such a testbed self. But without testing I agree with you that 10 sprites per image may be a good estimate!

Comment: but obvious, we can't create 1 for you, moreover it depends on your website traffic, website where you are hosting, css intelligence, etc

Answer (score 0):

I examined this further and this sort of hack named CSS sprites (as well as other hacky optimizations: base64 images in data-urls, CSS/Javascript concatenation) are needed because HTTP 1.1 makes all calls synchronous ([source](http://www.slideshare.net/bjarlestam/spdy-11723049)).

At this time (october 2012) these like hacks may be suitable for large sites with hundreds of HTTP calls per page, but [HTTP 2.0 is coming](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/wiki/Http2CfI) in few years (I assume) to support better techniques (eg. asynchronous calls) and makes hopefully these hacks unnecessary.

The problem with hacks is the reduced maintainability and when HTTP 2.0 is finally here, all the hacks may need to be removed to return the proper maintainability and/or to benefit fully from the advantages of HTTP 2.0 [if there are such](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/http20.html)). While waiting HTTP 2.0, consider eg. SPDY (which is the possible base for HTTP 2.0 according to [recent news](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/100312-ietf-starts-work-on-next-generation-263000.html), BUT check first carefully that other server modules doesn't interfere with SPDY and follow how the browser support for spdy increases (if it increases at all). Or if your site has only few or tens of http calls, think carefully if there are enough benefits of these hacks to cover the lowered maintainability.